# Why is my nav menu icon not inside the nav menu when the screen is small

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I have a navigation menu and it is responsive but when I put the three bar nav menu icon to open up the menu on small screens it is not in the menu, it is outside the menu and below it. I have provided this

[image]

I have tried to work with the padding and the margins but no use in my code.
@Bhaskar Here is all of my code

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
body {
    background-color: black;
    font-color: white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 50px;
    color: lightgreen;
    font-weight: 900;
}

ul, li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.6);
}
.topnav-li  {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    }
.topnav {;
    height: 30px; 
    border-bottom: groove grey;
    text-align: center;
  }

.topnav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 50px;
    color: lightgreen;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.6);
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .linkss {
    background-color: black;
  }
}

.content {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    border: groove grey;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .content {
    width: 400px;
  }
    .slide img {
    width: 400px;
  }
}

[data-component="slideshow"] .slide {
    display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

[data-component="slideshow"] .slide.active {
    display: block;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: grey;
  font-color: black;
}

.ld {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.myButton {
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #3e7327;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
    background-color:#77b55a;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #4b8f29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding:20px 30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #5b8a3c;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
}
.myButton:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
    background-color:#72b352;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}


@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,700italic,700,900italic,900);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300,500,600,700,800,900);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300,500,600,700,800,900);

#generic_price_table{
    background-color: #f0eded;
}

/*PRICE COLOR CODE START*/
#generic_price_table .generic_content{
    background-color: #fff;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price{
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_head_content .head_bg{
    border-color: #e4e4e4 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) #e4e4e4;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_head_content .head span{
    color: #525252;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_price_tag .price .sign{
    color: #414141;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_price_tag .price .currency{
    color: #414141;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_price_tag .price .cent{
    color: #414141;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_price_tag .month{
    color: #414141;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_feature_list ul li{  
    color: #a7a7a7;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_feature_list ul li span{
    color: #414141;
}
#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_feature_list ul li:hover{
    background-color: #E4E4E4;
    border-left: 5px solid #2ECC71;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_price_btn a{
    border: 1px solid #2ECC71; 
    color: #2ECC71;
} 

#generic_price_table .generic_content.active .generic_head_price .generic_head_content .head_bg,
#generic_price_table .generic_content:hover .generic_head_price .generic_head_content .head_bg{
    border-color:   #b48811;
    color: #fff;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content:hover .generic_head_price .generic_head_content .head span,
#generic_price_table .generic_content.active .generic_head_price .generic_head_content .head span{
    color: #fff;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content:hover .generic_price_btn a,
#generic_price_table .generic_content.active .generic_price_btn a{
    background-color: #2ECC71;
    color: #fff;
} 
#generic_price_table{
    margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
.row .table{
    padding: 28px 0;
}

/*PRICE BODY CODE START*/

#generic_price_table .generic_content{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_head_content{
    margin: 0 0 50px 0;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_head_content .head_bg{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 90px 1411px 23px 399px;
    position: absolute;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_head_content .head{
    padding-top: 40px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_head_content .head span{
    font-family: "Raleway",sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_price_tag{
    padding: 0 0 20px;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_price_tag .price{
    display: block;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_price_tag .price .sign{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 400;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_price_tag .price .currency{
    font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_price_tag .price .cent{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_price_tag .month{
    font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_feature_list ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_feature_list ul li{
    font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_feature_list ul li:hover{
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;

}
#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_feature_list ul li .fa{
    padding: 0 10px;
}
#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_price_btn{
    margin: 20px 0 32px;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_price_btn a{
    border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -ms-border-radius: 50px;
    -o-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#generic_price_table .generic_content,
#generic_price_table .generic_content:hover,
#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_head_content .head_bg,
#generic_price_table .generic_content:hover .generic_head_price .generic_head_content .head_bg,
#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_head_price .generic_head_content .head h2,
#generic_price_table .generic_content:hover .generic_head_price .generic_head_content .head h2,
#generic_price_table .generic_content .price,
#generic_price_table .generic_content:hover .price,
#generic_price_table .generic_content .generic_price_btn a,
#generic_price_table .generic_content:hover .generic_price_btn a{
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
} 
@media (max-width: 320px) { 
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #generic_price_table .generic_content{
        margin-bottom:75px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    #generic_price_table .col-md-3{
        float:left;
        width:50%;
    }
    
    #generic_price_table .col-md-4{
        float:left;
        width:50%;
    }
    
    #generic_price_table .generic_content{
        margin-bottom:75px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
}
#generic_price_table_home{
     font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.text-center h1,
.text-center h1 a{
    color: #7885CB;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.demo-pic{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.demo-pic:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#generic_price_table_home ul{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
}
#generic_price_table_home li{
    float: left;
}
#generic_price_table_home li + li{
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#generic_price_table_home li a{
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
#generic_price_table_home .blue{
    background: #3498DB;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
#generic_price_table_home .emerald{
    background: #2ECC71;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
#generic_price_table_home .grey{
    background: #7F8C8D;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
#generic_price_table_home .midnight{
    background: #34495E;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
#generic_price_table_home .orange{
    background: #E67E22;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
#generic_price_table_home .purple{
    background: #9B59B6;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
#generic_price_table_home .red{
    background: #E74C3C;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
#generic_price_table_home .turquoise{
    background: #1ABC9C;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

#generic_price_table_home .blue:hover,
#generic_price_table_home .emerald:hover,
#generic_price_table_home .grey:hover,
#generic_price_table_home .midnight:hover,
#generic_price_table_home .orange:hover,
#generic_price_table_home .purple:hover,
#generic_price_table_home .red:hover,
#generic_price_table_home .turquoise:hover{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
#generic_price_table_home .divider{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#generic_price_table_home .divider span{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    height: 2px;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 50px auto;
    line-height: 2px;
}
#generic_price_table_home .itemname{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px ;
    padding: 50px 0 20px ;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
}
#generic_price_table_home .itemnametext{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
}
#generic_price_table_home .footer{
    padding:40px 0;
}

.demo-button {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: table;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    outline-color: -moz-use-text-color;
    outline-style: none;
    outline-width: medium ;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.demo-button:hover{
    background-color: #666;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    
}
.bottom_btn:hover{
    background-color: #666;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}


.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

::selection {
  background: lightgreen;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="dl71d0_3NOeCeDCG9GnUDYn0wQCdcEkRC7HYGIN-uP0" />
<meta name="ezcoderz, Ezcoderz, EzCoderz, coding, code, Jason Wang, Hire A Coder, Hire, Programing" content="Ezcoderz is a service where people can Hire me to code for them for money, all the sites we code are easy and simple. 
Avrage cost to hire per hour is smaller compared to others.">


 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>EZcoderZ Hire a coder cheap and easy - we like programming.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<div class="linkss">
</ul><a href="index.html">Home</a>
<a href="about.html">About</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
<a href="price.html">Pricing</a>
</div>
<button onclick="darkMode()" class="ld">light mode on/off <i class="fa">&#xf042;</i></button>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  </div>
<br>
<div class="content">
    <div id="slideshow-example" data-component="slideshow">
        <div role="list">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="img/slide1.png" alt="IMAGE FAILED TO DISPLAY">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="img/slide2.png" alt="IMAGE FAILED TO DISPLAY">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="img/slide3.png" alt="IMAGE FAILED TO DISPLAY">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: row;">
<img src="img/logo.png" style="margin: auto; align: center;" /> 
<p style="text-align: center;"> I will make websites for you if your website you want me to make is not <b>easy</b> then I will not make it.
If you did not read the terms of service then I will not code for you. Websites I make will be a bit better or the same as this website. You can add $2 an hour to remove my water mark in your website.
My watermark is going to be that logo above this text. You may not refund anything that is 50 lines of code or more. Payment options are- check. There is a 100 hires per month limit.</p>
<a href="price.html" class="myButton">Hire Now</a>
<hr>
<h2>Why us?</h2>
<p>We will code for you really cheap and simple so when you hire a coder from us we will get the job done FAST. Go aahed and click Hire now!</p>
</div>

<br>
<footer style="text-align: center;">
  <h2>Copyright ezcoderz 2022 | <a href="terms.html">terms</a></h2>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
<script>
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
} 
function darkMode() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
} 

var slideshows = document.querySelectorAll('[data-component="slideshow"]');
slideshows.forEach(initSlideShow);

function initSlideShow(slideshow) {

    var slides = document.querySelectorAll(`#${slideshow.id} [role="list"] .slide`);

    var index = 0, time = 5000;
    slides[index].classList.add('active');

    setInterval( () => {
        slides[index].classList.remove('active');
        
        index++;
        if (index === slides.length) index = 0;

        slides[index].classList.add('active');

    }, time);
}
</script>
```

My code is above.

Comment: Hi - when I run your code snippet and click around, I'm not seeing the hamburger menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use flex box. Wrap your link tags in a list of a button.

```
<section class="nav-section">
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li>home</li>
            <li>blog</li>
            <li>about</li>
            <li>contact</li>
        </ul>
     <div> <button> Menu</button></div>
    </nav>
    <div><button class="mybtn"> on/off</button></div>  
</section>
```

You can take a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/imbhaskarn/pen/gOGZzjg) link

Comment: when I add it to my nav menu all the links go under the border and when I put it to mobile view the nav just looks like a disaster.

Comment: can you share all of the code

Comment: Ok I did just now.

Comment: div is a block level element therefore it takes all the horizontal space. I would suggest you to use flex blox. You should also watch youtube tutorial.  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp